# How can I save the current value of an UISlider to my NSUserDefaults in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have an app with two settings components, a `uiSlider` and a `uiSwitch`.

I know how to save option for the switch, this is what I'm doing:

```
@IBOutlet weak var settingA: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {

        settingA.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("settingA")
...
}

@IBAction func saveSettingA(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("setting A changed")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(settingA.on, forKey: "settingA")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Now I want to do the same for the slider. I already created an outlet to the slider and to the label next to it (that shows the value of the slider):

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderSlider: UISlider!
```

and also I have a method for updating the label every time user moves the slider around:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    sliderLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

But how can I save it to the `NSUserDefaults` every time user chooses new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you connect/add your/another action via Storyboard in this way:

[image]

Special stress here is that you should really only store the value once the user releases the button (otherwise you would redundantly make store requests to `NSUserDefaults`, which I'm sure you don't want), hence you can see I selected `Touch Up Outside` instead of `Value Changed` for the event.
The reason I phrased it like this *("connect/add your/another")*  is because you can connect multiple `@IBAction`s, for example one for the event `Value Changed` for when you want to observe the value changing and doing something when that happens and also as I demonstrated to act upon the user letting go of the slider.

Then, in order to store the value, you can do:

```
@IBAction func valueChangeEnded(slider: UISlider) {
    print("save to user defaults")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(slider.value, forKey: "slider_value")
  }
```

And read it back in like this:

```
let sliderValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("slider_value")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as it should, almost... now when I come back to the app I see the radius is updated properly, but the label still displays the default value and it gets updated when user touches the slider. Is there a way of updating the label in a similar way as the slider itself?

Comment: Sure, where do you set the label text ?

Comment: currently I'm changing the label in the method called `sliderValueChanged`, using this code: `var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    sliderLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"` (I put it in my original question :) )

Comment: What do you mean by "when I come back to the app" ?

Comment: By that I mean for example build it again from xcode - when I do that the slider has a properly updated value, but the label has the default text placed there by me programmatically. And when I start touching the slider, the method `sliderValueChanged` invokes and the label gets updated.

Comment: Sure, you can just do `sliderLabel.text = "\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey("slider_value"))"` in your `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: oh yeah I forgot about that completely! Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same logic in saveSettingA inside of the sliderValueChanged function.  Just save the sender.value object rather than the int value.

Answer (score 0):

> swift 4.2

1.In your view will appear.

```
fontSlider.setValue(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "slider_value"), animated: false)
```

2.Take another outlet from storyBoard as "editingDidEnd". In that function:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(fontSlider.value, forKey: "slider_value")
```

3.And finally in your ValueChanged Outlet.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(fontSlider.value, forKey: "slider_value")
```